# Laravel query builder for relation table whereHas and several values

Tags: laravel

I have a `Products` table. An `Attributes` table is attached to it, with one to many relation, this means that a product can have many different attributes. I need to filter the request in order to select, for example, all products whose origin is China. My request, it works with single value.

```
        Product::where('price','>',0)
                 ->orderBy('price', "asc")
                 ->with('attributes')
                 ->whereHas('attributes', function(Builder $query){
                  
                     $query->where('value_name', '=', 'China');
                     
                  })->get();
```

I need where the products have `China` and `Gray` attributes together
If there is only one parameter, then it works, but there can be a dynamic number of parameters and it is necessary to select only those products whose attributes will have, for example, the origin of China and the color Gray. But this query returns an empty result.

```
     $products = Product::where('price', '>', 0)
          ->orderBy('price', "asc")
           ->with('attributes')
           ->whereHas('attributes', function(Builder $query){
          
             $query->where('value_name','=' , 'China')
                   ->where('value_name','=' , 'Grey');
             
          })
        ->get();

part table Attributes bellow. 
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
| id | attribute_guid                       | attribute_name | value_guid                           | value_name | item_id |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
|  1 | 84c01488-bf53-11e9-80e3-00155dbf5a2a | Orign          | e4a32025-24d2-11eb-bf54-00505600fc59 | China      |       1 |
|  2 | 9790984e-1103-11ea-b773-b42e9983820e | Color          | 8acbe31e-ddfa-11ea-bf53-00505600fc59 | Grey       |       1 |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `where` method is the same as a `AND WHERE` on an SQL query. You'll need to use the `$query->where('value_name, 'China')->orWhere('value_name', 'Grey');` or use the `$query->whereIn('value_name', ['China', 'Grey'])`.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#or-where-clauses - `orWhere`
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses - additional `where` clauses

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I probably did not ask the question correctly, I only need those values ​​where there are at the same time "China" and "Grey".  If use `whereIn`  or `orWhere` will select all products where there is at least one attribute `China` or one attribute `Gray`. I need where the products have `China` and `Gray` attributes together . Like in an online store, you select attributes and only show products that match them.

Comment: @АлександрИнженер, oops, I understood it in the wrong way it seems, my bad. Have you tried chaining multiple `->whereHas` methods to the main query?

Comment: multiple ->whereHas its solution works! Maybe you know how to set `->whereHas` dynamically from an array? There can be many parameters for filtering and it is necessary to somehow create conditions on the fly  `->whereHas`